# How to filter datatable based on condition and ignoring case?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, datatables

guys I am trying to fetch the records from the datatable, while doing so, it is checking for case Like ABC  and abc are two different, I used StringComparer.OrdinalIgnorecase but it doesn't work. how can I fix this?

```
from tblproj in dt.AsEnumerable() 
where tblproj.Field<string>("ProjectStatus") == "Active" && 
      ( string.Equals(tblproj.Field<string>("ColumnName").StartsWith(searchText),StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || string.Equals(tblproj.Field<string>("ColumnName").Contains(searchText), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      || string.Equals(tblproj.Field<long>("ColumnName").ToString().Contains(searchText), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: What is the type of the result of [`String.StartsWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_StartsWith_System_String_) and [`String.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Contains_System_String_)? What parameters does [`String.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Equals_System_String_System_String_) take?

Comment: It will take string as parameter

Comment: And the return types and the type of `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` are not `string`s. Use the proper versions of `StartsWith` and `Contains` that take a `StringComparison` parameter.

Comment: How can i handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter what case its in? If not then just perform a .ToUpper() or .ToLower() on the values then do the comparison between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Using the correct versions of `String.Contains` and `String.StartsWith` to ignore case in the tests:

```
var ans = from tblproj in dt.AsEnumerable()
          where tblproj.Field<string>("ProjectStatus") == "Active" &&
                tblproj.Field<string>("ColumnName").StartsWith(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                tblproj.Field<string>("ColumnName").Contains(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                tblproj.Field<long>("ColumnName").ToString().Contains(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
          select tblproj;
```